# Bounding maximum of a function using sampling

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ which is nonconvex function difficult to optimize but easy to evaluate for a large number of samples. I am interested in obtaining the probability by which I can say that $\max f(x) \leq \bar f$ using the numerical evaluations of $f(x)$.

I am looking for the relationship between confidence level and the number of evaluations required.

How many evaluations are required to show that for $\delta \in [0,1]$
$$p\big (\max f(x) \leq \bar f \big ) \geq 1-\delta $$

Here, $x \in \Omega_x$ and $f(x)$ may or may not follow the normal distribution.

Comment: if $\bar f = \infty$ or $\delta = 0$, you're golden. Otherwise, I believe you'll need additional assumptions (conditions).

Comment: You can find a general result of a similar form in [Section 3.1.1 here](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2019/04/7153.pdf). Since you mention that it is easy to evaluate your function (but presumably hard to evaluate it's gradient), you should look at other derivative-free optimization methods in the above survey. If you can cheaply compute gradient information, then local optimization methods may be a good compromise if global optimization is hard.